# How to secure confidential data in memory

Tags: encryption

I am currently working on password manager. So far I used one encrypted database file to store all the passwords and then decrypted it at runtime with a derived user-entered master password. All log-in data was then loaded into memory to present it in a user interface: [image: User inteface]

I am searching for a more secure way to especially present the passwords. I could imagine encrypting every password until it is requested (for view, copy etc.) but I don't want to let the user enter his or her master password every time a password gets requested. So now I wouldn't have to store all the passwords in clear text in memory, but a password to decrypt them again. Is there any conceptual way to securely store this data, so the user must only decrypt it once?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question may be a better fit for [security.se].

Comment: Look at how [KeePassXC](https://github.com/keepassxreboot/keepassxc) and [Bitwarden](https://github.com/bitwarden) handle things.